# Update query with not in statement Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, notin

I am running an update statement with a `NOT IN` which contains another query which return me some visa numbers.

There seems too be an error which i cannot trace it, i doubt if i can use a query in `NOT IN`.. if some one could point out what i am doing wrong here.

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:





UPDATE HUDHAIFA.VISA_APP
    SET VISA_NO=(LPAD(TRIM(VISA_NO),8,'0'))
    WHERE LENGTH(VISA_NO) < 8
    AND VISA_NO IS NOT NULL
    AND VISA_NO NOT IN (  
      SELECT
      CASE
        WHEN LTRIM(VISA_NO, '0') IS NULL THEN VISA_NO
        WHEN LTRIM(VISA_NO, '0') IS NOT NULL THEN LTRIM(VISA_NO, '0') 
      END as VISA_NO
      FROM HUDHAIFA.VISA_APP
      WHERE LENGTH(VISA_NO) < 8
      GROUP BY CASE
        WHEN LTRIM(VISA_NO, '0') IS NULL THEN VISA_NO
        WHEN LTRIM(VISA_NO, '0') IS NOT NULL THEN LTRIM(VISA_NO, '0') 
      END
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      ORDER BY VISA_NO asc
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try removing `ORDER BY VISA_NO asc` and run. It is syntactically incorrect and not required in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, ORA-907 usually doesn't concert right parenthesis but means something like 'there is syntax error near this place so I cannot imagine what you want and guess you should close left parenthesis opened somewhere before'. In your case, as Bikash Ranjan Bhoi said, reason is `ORDER BY` clause which is senseless into such subquery.

You should also check that this subquery will never produce `NULL` among it's results. Both `IN` and `NOT IN` statements works requires not-null sets of values.